# Метаплейсхолдер к вопросу не помещается в поле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На метастранице [Задайте вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) плейсхолдер в поле Тема

> Опишите найденный дефект, предложение или тему для обсуждения. Будьте конкретны.

слишком длинный - он не помещается в поле и обрезается:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Предлагаю убрать «найденный», то есть `Опишите дефект, предложение или тему для обсуждения. Будьте конкретны.`

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а исправление планируется?

Comment: Извиняюсь, потерял дефект. Готово! Проверяйте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю убрать «найденный», то есть

> Опишите дефект, предложение или тему для обсуждения. Будьте конкретны.

PS: Из комментария [Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦](/questions/3269/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5#comment10581_3269).